# Where are the Condition flags stored in Y86-64 ISA?

Tags: memory, y86

The Condition Flags SF, ZF and OF, in the fictitious Y86-64 architecture, as described in Computer Systems, a Programmer's Perspective by Randall and Bryant.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably not reinventing the wheel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register